Black screen after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 LTS
After upgrading to 22.04 LTS I can't log in with my password. Black screen.
My computer is a lenovo V145 -Ast and the issue is known in the lenovo community-
no graphical driver. The solution -upgrading they proposed was not helpful because I did it before.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried  to install  ubuntu drivers. The answer was:"all available drivers Installed." So, it has to do with the lenovoV145 computer?
